# NameError: name 'f2py' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

after installing python, numpy and scipy_dist_utils i typed f2py onto the python interpretor
the result is as below

```
>>> f2py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    f2py
NameError: name 'f2py' is not defined
>>> import numpy
>>> f2py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    f2py
NameError: name 'f2py' is not defined
```

---

from numpy import f2py solved the problem
 but this does not work now
f2py -c --help-fcompiler

f2py -c --help-fcompiler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    f2py -c --help-fcompiler
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

> > > 

What has gone wrong? could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to *run* f2py, you do that from your command shell (bash or whatever on UNIX machines, CMD on Windows), not from the Python interpreter. There isn't a whole lot you can do with

Also, scipy_distutils is very, very old and not at all used anymore. Whatever instructions that told you to install that are incredibly out of date. For a somewhat more up to date set of instructions:

http://www.scipy.org/F2py

Answer (score 2):

You have to type:

```
import numpy.f2py
```

Also, be sure to have a recent version of `numpy`.

Comment: >>> import numpy.f2py
>>> f2py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    f2py
NameError: name 'f2py' is not defined     AND YES I HAVE THE LATEST VERSIONS OF NUMPY AND PYTHON

Answer (score 2):

Did you type `from numpy import f2py` before trying to use `f2py`?

Comment: numpy import f2py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy import f2py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: import numpy
>>> numpy import f2py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: from numpy import f2py
>>> f2py
<module 'numpy.f2py' from 'C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\__init__.py'> THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Kern is correct. You cannot run it from within python. I had a similar error on my windows computer. The problem is that f2py is not in the path.

You'll have to call f2py in the following method from the command prompt.

```
python C:\Path\to\f2py.py
```

That should allow it to be called.

As an example, I have python 3.4 installed in the C directory in the folder `Python34` with f2py in the subfolder `Scripts`. So, my call to f2py is `python C:\Python34\Scripts\f2py.py`.